# MySQL - Check out trigger not executing

Tags: mysql, trigger, date

Im implementing a trigger to be executed when the end date of a booking is passed

Its supposed to change a cats status within checked in from 1 to 0

when updating the table changing an ex booking cats stay to 1 it does not change it back to 0

This is the following script:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER CheckOut
BEFORE UPDATE ON BOOK
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 

    SET @CheckedInCat = ( SELECT Checked_In FROM CATTERY.BOOKCAT WHERE Ref = NEW.Ref );
    SET @StartDCopy = ( SELECT Start_Date FROM CATTERY.BOOK WHERE Ref = NEW.Ref );
    SET @EndDCopy = ( SELECT End_Date FROM CATTERY.BOOK WHERE Ref = NEW.Ref );
    Set @CurrrentDate = '2019-11-25';

    IF @CurrentDate >= @EndDCopy THEN
        IF CheckedInCat = 1 THEN
            UPDATE `CATTERY`.`CATINFO` SET `Checked_In` = '0' WHERE (`Chip_ID` = BOOKCAT.Chip_ID);
        END IF;
    END IF;
END |
DELIMITER |
```

Table structure:

```
create schema test;
use test;
CREATE TABLE BOOK( Ref INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Start_Date DATE NOT NULL, End_Date DATE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(Ref));
CREATE TABLE CATINFO( Chip_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, Checked_In TINYINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(Chip_ID));
CREATE TABLE BOOKCAT( Ref INT NOT NULL, Chip_ID INT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (Ref) REFERENCES BOOK(Ref), FOREIGN KEY (Chip_ID) REFERENCES CATINFO(Chip_ID));

INSERT INTO BOOK(Start_Date, End_Date) VALUES ('2019-11-22', '2019-11-25'),('2019-11-24', '2019-11-28'), ('2019-11-01','2019-11-02');
INSERT INTO CATINFO(Chip_ID, Checked_In) VALUES(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 0);
INSERT INTO BOOKCAT(Ref, Chip_ID) VALUES(1, 1),(2, 2),(2, 3),(3, 1);
```

it should be changing cat id 1 to Checked_In to 0, like the following:

```
# Chip_ID, Checked_In
1, 0
2, 1
3, 0
```

The current date is only a local variable for testing purposes

Comment: *Im implementing a trigger to be executed when the end date of a booking is passed* What event will fire your trigger? Who/what will alter `BOOK` table data which fires your trigger? Maybe you want to create event?

Comment: Its supposed to trigger before the booking table updates, this is my first trigger, have i done this incorrectly? @Akina

Comment: *Its supposed to trigger before the booking table updates* Who/what will update this table? Why it will update thos table? What if nobody/nothing updates the table? There must be the process external for MySQL which performs update action...